# Android privacy browser with "forward" button

Tags: android, web-browser

I currently use FireFox Focus as my Android browser. I would be willing to change, but only for something privacy based.

I am looking for a browser which has a “forward” button, as desktop browser do, which probably also means a “back button”, as I currently use the system “back”.

To be clear: if I visit page A, then B, then C, I want to be able to go back from C to B, then Back to A, forward to B, and forward again to C.

Chrome can do this, but I will not accept it as an answer, no matter how many privacy add-ins are suggested, because I simply do not trust Google.

In fact, I would prefer a browser with privacy “baked-in”, rather than having to install plugins. Something like Focus, InBrowser, DuckDuckGo, but it must have a forward button (and probably a back too, unless it recognizes that the system back button has been pressed).

preferably [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis). Or sub $10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox Focus itself matches your requirements as it has a "forward" button.

It is available from menu on the right side of the address bar (via button with three dots).

"back" is available via system back button.

Comment: Lolx!! How on earth did I mess that??!! Thanx a 1,000,000

Comment: @Mawg - I in turn had a large problem to figure out that I should use phone "back" button when I started using smartphone :)

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that if you go all the way back to the initial welcome screen, you can't go forward again :-(

Comment: From what I understand this is deliberate part of "privacy" part - it is treated as shortcut to "erase history".

Comment: Yes, I can see it as "close session" or closing the last tab (alas)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of privacy is wanted and what is considered as acceptable tradeoffs one may also use Tor based browser. "Orfox Tor Browser for Android" by The Tor Project combined with "Orbot: Proxy with Tor" are clearly ones for the Adroid.

It is Firefox-based so it includes wanted buttons.

It is also using Tor with following consequences

- it is more complicated: two apps instead of one, more things may require setup - especially if your country banned Tor (though in a country attempting to block Tor it is also far more useful to use Tor)
- user is effectively anonymous (with all benefits of that)
- user is effectively anonymous (with all negatives of that - for example Wikipedia blocks editing for Tor users as otherwise it would be impossible to block anybody from editing)
- some sites limit/block access with Tor without a good reason (for example Google search)
- Tor hides from ISP etc most of what you are doing (for details please see https://www.torproject.org - there are many ways to leak identify and some info like "this user is using Tor" is available for an attacker)
- Tor allows accessing censored websites

Comment: But, does it have a forward button?

Comment: There is also [InBrowser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nu.tommie.inbrowser), which is so paranoid that it closes itself if you switch to another app :-)

Comment: @Mawg Yes, there is both forward and back button - hidden in a similar location as Firefox Focus. ("It is Firefox-based so it includes wanted buttons.")